# XML parsing from string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a problem when trying to parse an XML from a string. I'm using chrome, and the string is written by an websocket.
This is the XML from the string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
    <event name="newchannel">
        <privilege>call,all</privilege> 
        <channel>SIP/NTECH-00000008</channel> 
        <channelstate>0</channelstate> 
        <channelstatedesc>Down</channelstatedesc> 
        <calleridnum>0725922523</calleridnum> 
        <calleridname /> <accountcode /> 
        <uniqueid>1305017047.8</uniqueid>
        <actionid>1305017047_0_ALL_ALL</actionid> 
    </event>
```

The data that I'm trying to get is `<calleridnum>0725922523</calleridnum>`.
With this number, add a new row into a DOM built table (1 row/new event).

This is the jQuery that prints out a new row, but empty:

`var nrtel = $(afisare).find("calleridnum").text();`

I've tried other examples but they don't print out anything.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Sebastian

**EDIT**
I get these errors in the Chrome Console

```
3642Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (Presentation Allowed, Not Screened)&lt;/cid-callingpres&gt;
 &lt;actionid&gt;1305023821_0_ALL_ALL&lt;/actionid&gt;
&lt;/event&gt;
Sizzle.errorjquery-1.5.2.js:3642
Sizzle.filterjquery-1.5.2.js:3628
Sizzlejquery-1.5.2.js:3418
Sizzlejquery-1.5.2.js:4507
Sizzlejquery-1.5.2.js:3482
Sizzlejquery-1.5.2.js:4507
jQuery.fn.extend.findjquery-1.5.2.js:4747
jQuery.jQuery.fn.jQuery.initjquery-1.5.2.js:173
jQuery.jQueryjquery-1.5.2.js:25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it and it just works.

If you've used firebug to test your code, check the nrtel var, you might find that it contains what you want. The semicolons at the end of the line made firebug return undefined.